# md-table in Angular Material 2 not working

Tags: angular, angular-material2

I was just trying to use the newly introduced datatable in Angular Material beta 2.0.0-beta.8 but i can't get it to work as i'm stuck with this error:

```
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'columnsChange' of undefined
at MdTable.webpackJsonp.../../../cdk/@angular/cdk.es5.js.CdkTable.ngAfterContentInit (cdk.es5.js:1950)
at callProviderLifecycles (core.es5.js:11174)
at callElementProvidersLifecycles (core.es5.js:11155)
at callLifecycleHooksChildrenFirst (core.es5.js:11139)
at checkAndUpdateView (core.es5.js:12239)
at callViewAction (core.es5.js:12601)
at execEmbeddedViewsAction (core.es5.js:12559)
at checkAndUpdateView (core.es5.js:12237)
at callViewAction (core.es5.js:12601)
at execComponentViewsAction (core.es5.js:12533)
at checkAndUpdateView (core.es5.js:12242)
at callViewAction (core.es5.js:12601)
at execEmbeddedViewsAction (core.es5.js:12559)
at checkAndUpdateView (core.es5.js:12237)
at callViewAction (core.es5.js:12601)
```

I imported both MdTableModule and CdkTableModule into my app's module.

The DataSource implementation looks like this:

```
 import {OnInit, Component} from "@angular/core";
import {SetupSummaryService} from "./setupSummaryService";
import {BehaviorSubject} from 'rxjs/BehaviorSubject';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';
import {DataSource} from "@angular/cdk";
import 'rxjs/add/operator/startWith';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/merge';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';


@Component({
  templateUrl: 'setupSummary.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['setupSummary.component.scss'],
  providers: [SetupSummaryService]
})

export class SetupSummaryComponent implements OnInit {

  displayedColumns = ['userId', 'userName', 'progress', 'color'];
  exampleDatabase = new ExampleDatabase();
  dataSource: ExampleDataSource | null;
  constructor() {
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
        this.dataSource = new ExampleDataSource(this.exampleDatabase);

  }

}
/** Constants used to fill up our data base. */
const COLORS = ['maroon', 'red', 'orange', 'yellow', 'olive', 'green', 'purple',
  'fuchsia', 'lime', 'teal', 'aqua', 'blue', 'navy', 'black', 'gray'];
const NAMES = ['Maia', 'Asher', 'Olivia', 'Atticus', 'Amelia', 'Jack',
  'Charlotte', 'Theodore', 'Isla', 'Oliver', 'Isabella', 'Jasper',
  'Cora', 'Levi', 'Violet', 'Arthur', 'Mia', 'Thomas', 'Elizabeth'];

export interface UserData {
  id: string;
  name: string;
  progress: string;
  color: string;
}
/** An example database that the data source uses to retrieve data for the table. */
export class ExampleDatabase {
  /** Stream that emits whenever the data has been modified. */
  dataChange: BehaviorSubject<UserData[]> = new BehaviorSubject<UserData[]>([]);
  get data(): UserData[] { return this.dataChange.value; }

  constructor() {
    // Fill up the database with 100 users.
    for (let i = 0; i < 100; i++) { this.addUser(); }
  }

  /** Adds a new user to the database. */
  addUser() {
    const copiedData = this.data.slice();
    copiedData.push(this.createNewUser());
    this.dataChange.next(copiedData);
  }

  /** Builds and returns a new User. */
  private createNewUser() {
    const name =
      NAMES[Math.round(Math.random() * (NAMES.length - 1))] + ' ' +
      NAMES[Math.round(Math.random() * (NAMES.length - 1))].charAt(0) + '.';

    return {
      id: (this.data.length + 1).toString(),
      name: name,
      progress: Math.round(Math.random() * 100).toString(),
      color: COLORS[Math.round(Math.random() * (COLORS.length - 1))]
    };
  }
}

/**
 * Data source to provide what data should be rendered in the table. Note that the data source
 * can retrieve its data in any way. In this case, the data source is provided a reference
 * to a common data base, ExampleDatabase. It is not the data source's responsibility to manage
 * the underlying data. Instead, it only needs to take the data and send the table exactly what
 * should be rendered.
 */
export class ExampleDataSource extends DataSource<any> {
  constructor(private _exampleDatabase: ExampleDatabase) {
    super();
  }

  /** Connect function called by the table to retrieve one stream containing the data to render. */
  connect(): Observable<UserData[]> {
    return this._exampleDatabase.dataChange;
  }

  disconnect() {}
}
```

and here is my HTML template:

```
  <md-table [dataSource]="dataSource">

  <!--- Note that these columns can be defined in any order.
        The actual rendered columns are set as a property on the row definition" -->

  <!-- ID Column -->
  <ng-container cdkColumnDef="userId">
    <md-header-cell *cdkHeaderCellDef> ID </md-header-cell>
    <md-cell *cdkCellDef="let row"> {{row.id}} </md-cell>
  </ng-container>

  <!-- Progress Column -->
  <ng-container cdkColumnDef="progress">
    <md-header-cell *cdkHeaderCellDef> Progress </md-header-cell>
    <md-cell *cdkCellDef="let row"> {{row.progress}}% </md-cell>
  </ng-container>

  <!-- Name Column -->
  <ng-container cdkColumnDef="userName">
    <md-header-cell *cdkHeaderCellDef> Name </md-header-cell>
    <md-cell *cdkCellDef="let row"> {{row.name}} </md-cell>
  </ng-container>

  <!-- Color Column -->
  <ng-container cdkColumnDef="color">
    <md-header-cell *cdkHeaderCellDef>Color</md-header-cell>
    <md-cell *cdkCellDef="let row" [style.color]="row.color"> {{row.color}} </md-cell>
  </ng-container>

</md-table>
```

I have followed url https://material.angular.io/components/table/overview

as a guide to implement this.

Comment: can you create a `plunker`

Comment: @Aravind, I tried creating plunker, but its not allowing me to add Angular Material beta 2.0.0-beta.8. Sorry, I am new to plunker i tried adding it from packages and its not available Is there any other way todo it.

Comment: @user1188867 You can try re-creating it here: http://plnkr.co/edit/o077B6uEiiIgkC0S06dd

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to add the following lines to your `html` file:

```html
<md-header-row *cdkHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></md-header-row>
<md-row *cdkRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></md-row>
```

So that your `html` file looks like this:

```html
<md-table [dataSource]="dataSource">
  <!--- Note that these columns can be defined in any order.
    The actual rendered columns are set as a property on the row definition" -
  ->
  <!-- ID Column -->
  <ng-container cdkColumnDef="userId">
    <md-header-cell *cdkHeaderCellDef> ID </md-header-cell>
    <md-cell *cdkCellDef="let row"> {{row.id}} </md-cell>
  </ng-container>

  <!-- Progress Column -->
  <ng-container cdkColumnDef="progress">
    <md-header-cell *cdkHeaderCellDef> Progress </md-header-cell>
    <md-cell *cdkCellDef="let row"> {{row.progress}}% </md-cell>
  </ng-container>

  <!-- Name Column -->
  <ng-container cdkColumnDef="userName">
    <md-header-cell *cdkHeaderCellDef> Name </md-header-cell>
    <md-cell *cdkCellDef="let row"> {{row.name}} </md-cell>
  </ng-container>

  <!-- Color Column -->
  <ng-container cdkColumnDef="color">
    <md-header-cell *cdkHeaderCellDef>Color</md-header-cell>
    <md-cell *cdkCellDef="let row" [style.color]="row.color"> {{row.color}} 
    </md-cell>
  </ng-container>

  <md-header-row *cdkHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></md-header-row>
  <md-row *cdkRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></md-row>
</md-table>
```

[Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/wOwLDRpHg368FJ7vvVKb?p=preview)